# Setting up play new instead of sbt new to start a project

Tags: scala, playframework

Seems that play is not in the brew install list. How do i install it as a standalone command? Most of the books i see also start exercises with

```
play new hello
```

I have running projects with `sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8` but i want to able to use play as a command as well.

Comment: Easiest way I can think of off the top of my head would be to write a command line alias.

Comment: Using SBT is now the standard way

Comment: @cchantep yeah i get that now. So i should just ignore the examples that start with play?

Comment: Yes, or make an alias which does the `sbt` stuff under the hood.

Comment: Rather yes (alias would be a poor workaround)

Comment: cool @cchantep i would accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SBT is now the standard way, so `play` command is deprecated, and should no longer be used anyway.